# MSBuild.exe 15.0 calls cl.exe and link.exe from wrong Visual Studio directory

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have two Visual Studio installed on my system: VS 2015 and VS 2017.
I run msbuild explicitly from the VS 2017 location:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio"\2017\WDExpress\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe build/binding.sln /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64
```

Since I call msbuild from the VS 2017 I expect it to take the tools from VS 2017 as well, but it does not work!

The "normal" Verbosity level shows that msbuild calls C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe, so it takes them from the older VS 2015 that is wrong.

If I use even more verbose level (/clp:Verbosity=diagnostic) I see that msbuild takes the properties file from the wrong location as well. The message is:

```
Property reassignment: $(VCInstallDir_140)="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (55,5)
```

The indeed properties file is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props.

The PATH variable is correct and does not contain anything that points to the older VS 2015. The variable VS140COMNTOOLS is unset.

Is it the expected behaviour and how can I tell msbuild to use the tools from VS 2017?

Answer (score 0):

> MSBuild.exe 15.0 calls cl.exe and link.exe from wrong Visual Studio directory

Please try to call the MSBuild from:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`

and add the parameter `/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0` in the command line, like:

```
msbuild.exe build/binding.sln /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the option /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0, but it did not take effect.
Later I found what was the reason of that behaviour: my *.vcxproj file has the tag

```
<PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
```

Once I changed it to **v141** the msbuild started to take compiler and linker properly. So, it turned that msbuild first of all respects this parameter and only then probably command line options or/and PATH variable.